# Is there something comparable to XPath for registry entries?

Tags: powershell, xpath, registry

I want to get a list of all values named Test and matching a key pattern like this:

```
HKCU\Foo\*\Test
```

Assuming there are two keys in Foo, this should output

```
Hello # value of HKCU\Foo\Sub1\Test
World # value of HKCU\Foo\Sub1\Test
```

How can that be done using e.g. PowerShell? (using PowerShell 7)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to achieve this by utilizing the Get-ChildItem cmdlet to list the registry keys and the Get-ItemPropertyValue cmdlet to get the value of the specified property. In your case, you can do the following:

```
$path = "HKCU:\Foo\"
$keyPattern = "Test"

# Get all subkeys under HKCU:\Foo\
$subkeys = Get-ChildItem -Path $path

# Loop through each subkey and get the value of the 'Test' property
foreach ($subkey in $subkeys) {
    try {
        $value = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $subkey.PSPath -Name $keyPattern -ErrorAction Stop

        # Print the value
        Write-Output $value
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "Value not found for key: $($subkey.PSPath)"
    }
}
```

This script will list all the values under HKCU:\Foo*\Test as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using [Get-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-7.4) and [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.4) you can accomplish this goal with ease and simplicity.

### PowerShell

```
Get-Item -Path HKCU:\Foo\*\Test  | 
    Where-Object {$_ -match "Test"} |
        Select Name, Property;
```

#### Output

```
Name                            Property
----                            --------
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Foo\Sub1\Test {Test}  
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Foo\sub2\Test {Test}
```

### Or PowerShell

```
(Get-Item -Path HKCU:\Foo\*\Test | Where-Object {
    $_ -match "Test"} | 
        Select-Object Name, Property).Foreach({
            Write-Host "Hello $($_.Property) value of $($_.Name)"
            });
```

#### Output

```
Hello Test value of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Foo\Sub1\Test 
Hello Test value of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Foo\sub2\Test
```

### Example Config

[image]